# Pure Python Tidy-like application/library

Tags: python, html, xml, xhtml, tidy

I'm looking for a pure Python library which works like Tidy. Please kindly advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ElementTree Tidy HTML Tree Builder](https://github.com/atizo/elementtidy).

Comment: Thanks but not something I was looking for. I need those in pure python and do not depend on Tidy.

Comment: Looking for the same thing too - but without the dependency of the tidylib C library.